# Usage of different ViewResolver in Spring Mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, view

I am a beginner in spring-mvc. While going through the view resolvers, I am able to understand that how to use following view resolvers:

> BeanNameViewResolver,InternalResourceViewResolver and
>   UrlBasedViewResolver

I have already gone through the google to understand but still i am not clear about their pros and cons over each other.

How one should decide when to use which view Resolver.

If someone can help me in understanding that,it would be a great help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`InternalResourceViewResolver` is a subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver`.

`UrlBasedViewResolver` and `InternalResourceViewResolver` are often used in MVC application where the controller return the name of the view that should been rendered. The controller return an logical name of the view, and the resolver made it a file name (of the jsp), by adding some pre - and postfix. For example: logical view name return by the controller: `main/example`, prefix: `/WEB-INF/pages/`, postfix: `.jsp` -> `/WEB-INF/pages/main/example.jsp` gets rendered with the model-data provided by the controller

- The `UrlBasedViewResolver` needs a [`View`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/View.html) class (like the most other ViewResolvers too). *(very brif: The view class is responsible for rendering, while the resolver is responsible to pick the right template/...)* The view used in `UrlBasedViewResolver` has to be an subclass of [`AbstractUrlBasedView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractUrlBasedView.html).
- The `InternalResourceViewResolver` is convenient subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver` that has be default already a configured view: [`InternalResourceView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceView.html) (or [`JstlView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/JstlView.html) when Jstl is present). So it is the right resolver when JSPs are used as template engine.

*There are other `AbstractUrlBasedView` implementations, for example for JasperReports, Freemaker, Velocity, Tiles, .... Most of them has a convenient subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver` too.*

- `BeanNameViewResolver` very very old resolvers, from the old Spring 2.0 time. At this time each controller was for handling one URL. At this time there was no `@RequestMapping` annotation, and one has to tell Spring which controller was for which url. One could list them all, or have this Resolver, that was able to map url->controller by the controller name. Since Spring 3.0 (more exact since 2.5) and Springs annotation support, this resolver is used very rarely.

Comment: OK.Let me tell you my understanding from your answer.UrlBasedViewResolver can be used only for static content and we can't use the InternalResourceViewResolver for the static content.Please correct me if I am wrong. Also if you can explain what it means "URL gets translated to an view-template name".

Comment: So we can use jsp only while using InternalResourceViewResolver but if we use UrlBasedViewResolver there are multiple options for view technology. Right ?

Comment: Manish: yes, and for a lot of them there are already convenient subclass's (with a meaningfull name)

Answer (score 2):

When  your Spring application loads there is default ViewResolver that gets loaded - `InternalResourceViewResolver`. You can refer to the default beans that gets initialized in `DisplacherServlet.properties` in `spring-webmvc` jar In case of View Resolvers it is -

> org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver

which essentially returns a `JSTL` view.

There are lot of URLBasedViewResolvers like -

1. InternalResourceViewResolver
2. VelocityViewReolver
3. FreeMarkerViewReolver
4. ThymeleafViewResolver
5. XsltViewReolver

Yup you read it right. `InternalResourceViewResolver` is a convenient subclass of `UrlBasedViewResolver`.

If you want to know more about these View Resolvers see - http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-view-resolver.jsp

**NOTE** : Important point to note in case of chaining of view resolvers. In the chain Spring moves on to next View resolver only if current View resolver returns null. Some URLBasedViewResolvers (Tiles, Velocity,Freemarker) check if resource exist and return null. So they can be anywhere in the view resolver chain. Others must be last (JSTL/JSP, XSLT, JSON)

Comment: Hi Aniket.Thanks for your answer.Let me share my understanding. We can use jsp only while using InternalResourceViewResolver but if we use UrlBasedViewResolver there are multiple options for view technology. Right ?

Comment: Essentially a JSTL view. It can be a JSP or simply HTML.